# How to parse /Date(xxxx)/ in KQL?

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-powershell, kql

In Windows PowerShell, I used `ConvertTo-Json` on an object containing a DateTime.

This serializes the date to a format like: `/Date(1680994874000)/`

Now, I want to use my json output file as 'externaldata' in Kusto (not ingest it), but I can't find a built in way to parse `/Date(1680994874000)/`.

Here's what I have so far, but was wondering if there was something built in and not so ugly...

```
let events = externaldata (EventName:string, StartTime:string)
[h@"sasUri"]
with (format="multijson");
events 
| extend StartTime2 = unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(substring(StartTime,6, strlen(StartTime)-8)))
```

Comment: Looks like you have a linux time and trying to add milliseconds. A linux date starts at 1/1/1970. Try : $date = [DateTime]::Parse('1/1/1970'); $date = $date.AddMilliseconds(1680994874000);  Results will give Saturday, April 8, 2023 11:01:14 PM The results will be UTC time.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` on PowerShell Core doesn't produce `/Date(1680994874000)/`, it produces a standard ISO8601 string. In what environment did you execute `ConvertTo-Json`? What OS versino? `Get-Date | ConvertTo-Json` returns `"2023-04-25T13:36:07.5324789+03:00"` in PowerShell Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using Windows PowerShell - I didn't know that `ConvertTo-Json` in pwsh gave you a readable datetime, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sample datatable and assuming *StartTime* will be in */Date(1680994874000)/* format.
I have used `parse` command to extract data from *StartTime*.

**Sample query**

```
datatable (EventName:string,StartTime : string )
["event1","/Date(1680994874000)/"]
| parse StartTime with * "/Date(" StartTime1 ")/"
| extend ActualRequiredTime = unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(tolong(StartTime1))
| project ActualRequiredTime
```

**Result**

[image]